# Can a child execute waitpid() and wait() in C, Unix

Tags: c, unix, wait

In Unix, C. After a `fork()`, usually followed by a `wait()` or `waitpid()` to wait the `child` terminate. But can the `child` execute the `wait()`? The `child` doesn't have a `_child_`, so when it execute the `wait()`, what will happen?

Comment: It's behavior is described in the man page you can acccess by typing man 2 wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no child proccess for the child proces so `wait()` will return -1. From the man page:

> wait(): on success, returns the process ID of the terminated child;
>          on error, -1 is returned.